# Regular expression to match a file path with certain prefix

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-lookarounds

In a MongoDB 4.0 we have documents containing paths like this:

```
/abcd/name.txt
/abcd/efg/name2.txt
/abcd/gha/name3.txt
/ab/gha/name3.txt
```

I am trying to create a query with regular expression that would match lines with files that are in a specified directory (path prefix) and not match directories. For example:

There is only file `name.txt` in `/abcd/`.

My first attempt with regular expression was like this:

```regex
/\/abcd\/((?!\/).)*/gm
```

Unfortunately this matches also second and third line with directories.

[Regexr.com](https://regexr.com/40j3j)

```
/abcd/name.txt
/abcd/efg/name2.txt
/abcd/gha/name3.txt
```

Next attempts was like this:

```regex
/^(?=\/abcd\/)((?!\/).)*/gm
```

but this expression did not match anything.

Which regular expression would match the first line (file name in directory /abcd/) and exclude second and third (directories)?

Comment: Try `/^\/abcd\/[^\/]*$/`

Comment: `^` =startsWith and `$` = endsWith. Try to put these operators

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: No match unfortunately.

Comment: Show how you are using it.

Comment: I updated the post with link expression on regexr.com

Comment: No need posting any online tester tests. How are you using it in the target environment?

Comment: Ok, if you can't show it another way, here is [my regex online demo](https://regexr.com/40j4q) and *matches* the first line. There, instead of `[^\/]`, we must use `[^\/\n]` to avoid overflow to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need groups and lookaheads - it's only regex match in mongo. The query could be as simple as

```
db.collection.find({fieldname:/^\/abcd\/[^\/]+$/})
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct solution. I made it too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
/^\/abcd\/([^\/]+\.*$)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/rJNFs9/1

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the extention, like: `/\/abcd\/((?!\/).)*\./gm`
Here in action: [regexr](https://regexr.com/40j6d)